# How do I get full URL to an image in a Rails asynchronous mailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, actionmailer

I want to have emails I send out with ActionMailer contain images that link back to my app.  In my development environment, for example:

```
<img src="http://myfullappurl.dev/assets/myimage.png">
```

I have this in my development.rb

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = 'myfullappurl.dev'
config.action_mailer.asset_host = config.action_controller.asset_host
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'myfullappurl.dev', only_path: false }
```

But I can not get my mail templates to render a full URL in any of these way:

```
asset_path('myimage.png')
asset_path('myimage.png', only_path: false)
image_url('myimage.png')
```

A lot of similar questions on this topic are answered by doing something like this:

```
"#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{asset_path('image.png')}"
```

But because my mails are sent asynchronously with Sidekiq, there is no `request` object like there would be if they were sent synchronously in a controller.

Is there an obvious thing I am missing, or do I have to fight against Rails to do this?  I am using Rails 4, but I am sure that anything that works in 3.1/3.2 should do just fine.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Well this is odd behaviour, but I've resolved this issue.  It turns out that unless the action_mailer.asset_host starts with `http://` then it will be ignored.  There is a Regex in `actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb` that defines a valid ActionMailer URI:

```
URI_REGEXP = %r{^[-a-z]+://|^(?:cid|data):|^//}
```

However, if you put a `http://` in front of the `action_controller.asset_host` then you will end up with links to `http://http://myfullappurl.dev`

So to resolve it I had to add the following to my `development.rb`

```
 config.action_controller.asset_host = 'myfullappurl.dev'
 config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'http://myfullappurl.dev'
```

Just to be clear, this is Rails 4.0.0beta1 with the emails being sent asynchronously with Sidekiq, I am not sure if this affects Rails 3.

Comment: THANK YOU. This was the solution for getting rails 4.1.1 to display full image urls in HTML Emails.

Comment: yet another underrated answers on SO. 
also, i think its better to use https in most cases which are not dev env.

Comment: I did not experience any issues when adding the protocol to `action_controller.asset_host`, not sure if that behaviour has changed. The fix itself works just like described. :)

Comment: @lime what Rails versions are you working with? Glad to hear that the behaviour has changed :)

Comment: @cmaitchison I'm on 4.2, though I didn't find any change in `asset_url_helper` that would explain the difference. Let's hope it doesn't reappear.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I'm using Rails 5.0.6 and still had this problem.

Answer (score 9):

I believe you need to set these in your config

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://localhost:3000' #Or your domain
config.action_mailer.asset_host = config.action_controller.asset_host
```

Comment: I've got those configured.  Using Pow in dev, hence the .dev extension.

Answer (score 3):

in your environment file(i.e development.rb) :-

```
config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'http://localhost:3000' #Or your domain
```

in your mailer view file:-

```
<%= image_tag('image_name.jpg') %>
```

or

```
<img src="<%= image_url('image.jpg') %>" %>
```