# Images in emails sent from Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, erb

When I send links in an email from a Ruby on Rails application, I use the `link_to` function:

```
<%= link_to @user.name, controller: 'users', action: 'show', id: @user.id, only_path: false %>
```

This will produce a link like this:

```
http://www.example.com/users/58
```

Or if I'm on my development environment:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/58
```

How do I do the same with images? I've tried:

```
<%= image_tag "/invitations/#{@invitation.id}/open.png", only_path: false %>
```

I was hoping to see:

```
<img alt="Open" src="http://www.example.com/invitations/43/open.png" />
```

But I got this instead unfortunately:

```
<img alt="Open" only_path="false" src="/invitations/43/open.png" />
```

How do I get `img` tags to use the full URL based on the host I specified in my environment files?

Comment: Have you checked the accepted answer of this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490327/how-do-i-get-full-url-to-an-image-in-a-rails-asynchronous-mailer?rq=1 it is mentioned a weird behavior of AssetUrlHelper, perhaps you Rails version is affected

Comment: This is not an asset

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add this config to your development.rb file

```
config.action_mailer.asset_host = "http://localhost:3000"
```

Comment: The URL I want is not for an asset

Comment: An image is an asset. It did not work then I guess ?