# Rails image doesn't show up in mailers

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I send 2 types of e-mails in my application: welcome mailer, reset password mailer. I need to have the same logo at the top of each of them. I thought it will be easy job to do but unfortunately the logo seems to be broken[image: check-here]. Here is my for welcome mailer code:

`views/devise/layouts/devise_mailer.html.erb`

```
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <%= image_tag("logo.png", class: 'logo', align: :center) %>
          <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Based on docs I've added asset_host to the config file https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#adding-images-in-action-mailer-views

`config/development.rb`

```
config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'localhost:3000'
```

The logo itself is in `app/assets/images/logo.png`.

Comment: Try adding the protocol for the host, i.e. `config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'http://localhost:3000'` ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15539534))

Comment: Nope, that's not it - nothing changed

Comment: What is the output of the development log or server? What is the output of the developer console? What is the output of the element in the DOM/inspector?